# gstreamer-properties on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Please how do I open gstreamer properties on ubuntu 16.04. I tried this

```
    $ gstreamer-properties
```

on the command line but it gave me this error

```
    gstreamer-properties: command not found.
```

Please I would appreciate your help